# xcodebuild: error: Scheme Runner is not currently configured for the build action (another question)

Tags: flutter

I think I messed up some of the configuration in Xcode while I was trying to run my project from a physical device and now the project is not even running on my Mac simulation. Here is the error code below when I try to run my app.

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    xcodebuild: error: Scheme Runner is not currently configured
    for the build action.
```

There seems to be a problem setting up the Xcode development team when I look into it.

Here is the picture:

[image]

After reading through Stack Overflow, watching YouTube, and trying every possible solution I could find to fix this iOS simulation error, none of them worked for me so far and I don't know why.

Initially there were a lot of errors showing up on the terminal, but after deleting the Podfile in the IOS folder and reinstalling it and cleaning the Flutter project, there are now fewer errors showing up. Here is the error that is keep showing up.

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    xcodebuild: error: Scheme Runner is not currently configured
    for the build action.
```

There seems to be a problem setting up the Xcode development team when I look into it. Here is the picture of Xcode version I'm using:

[image]

and the Xcode window is here:

[image]

What's going on here?